# best way to process images already on S3 (rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, image, amazon-s3

I have a set of images on Amazon S3, and I'd like to automatically generate thumbnails for them to serve on my site.

I've considered Cloudinary, but it seems that I'd have to copy over all my images to Cloudinary servers first. I want to keep them on S3.

I've considered Dragonfly, but it seems that Dragonfly only works with files I'd upload after installing Dragonfly. I already have uploaded all my files.

What's a good solution for me? I'm in a Rails environment (rails 3.2).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If it's just a 'set of images' it's not really that well structured. You're better off reorganizing the way you store and manage images.

Try [Paperclip](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip%E2%80%8E).

```
class ModelName < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessible :image #more here
  has_attached_file :image, :styles => { :large => "450x450>", :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "150x150>" },
    :storage => :s3,
    :s3_credentials => "#{Rails.root}/config/s3.yml",
    :path => "people/:style/:id/:filename",
    :s3_protocol => "https"

   def original_image_url
     image.url
   end

   def large_image_url
     image.url(:large)
   end

   def medium_image_url
     image.url(:medium)
   end

   def small_image_url
     image.url(:thumb)
   end

 #etc

 end
```

Then simply do this to assign an existing image to an existing instance through the console:

```
require 'uri'
@instance.image = open(URI::encode(url))
@instance.save
# s3 will now contain the images in the appropriate sizes in the format specified above.
```

Since the original will also be saved, I'd advise to then delete the 'set of images' on s3 you started with, otherwise you'll be duplicating them.

Comment: It turns out I was wrong about Dragonfly -- dragonfly can work with already-uploaded files. I'm using that and it's working out great. Thanks for the advice, though, Niall.

Answer (score 0):

I was wrong about Dragonfly. You can use Dragonfly on already-uploaded files. I'm using it on my project and it's working out great.

Comment: It would be great if you explained how to do this with Dragonfly.